# For what reason did systemd stop starting?

Tags: systemd, cron

he last time the script ran was 13 hours ago, although there are no errors. How do I know what's causing it? systemd worked without interruption for about 2 months

```
root@instance:~# systemctl status croncam.service
● croncam.service - Cam online
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/croncam.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-07-15 02:25:12 MSK; 13h ago
TriggeredBy: ● croncam.timer
   Main PID: 107552 (bashtophp.sh)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 28554)
     Memory: 9.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/croncam.service
             ├─107552 /bin/bash /root/bashtophp.sh
             └─107553 php-cgi -f /var/www/website/public/cam2/camengine.php cron=true

Jul 15 02:25:12 instance systemd[1]: Started Cam online.
Jul 15 02:25:13 instance bashtophp.sh[107553]: <br>здратути<br><pre>Array
Jul 15 02:25:13 instance bashtophp.sh[107553]: (
Jul 15 02:25:13 instance bashtophp.sh[107553]:     [time] => 2022-07-15%2002:15:12
Jul 15 02:25:13 instance bashtophp.sh[107553]:     [status] => 0
Jul 15 02:25:13 instance bashtophp.sh[107553]: )



root@instance:~# systemctl status croncam.timer
● croncam.timer - Run every 10 minutes
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/croncam.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-07-03 13:56:01 MSK; 1 weeks 5 days ago
    Trigger: n/a
   Triggers: ● croncam.service

Jul 03 13:56:01 instance systemd[1]: Started Run every 10 minutes.
```

I assume that if I restart it, it will work as before, but I would like to know the reason for this stoppage.

service

```
[Unit]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Description=Cam online                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[Service]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Type=simple                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
ExecStart=/root/bashtophp.sh
```

timer

```
[Unit]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Description=Run every 10 minutes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[Timer]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
OnBootSec=1min                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
OnUnitActiveSec=10min                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Unit=croncam.service                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[Install]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

bashtophp.sh

```
php-cgi -f /var/www/website/public/cam2/camengine.php cron=true
```

No errors in apache2 logs... Where else can I look to see what might have caused this stoppage?

Comment: Try the journal: `journcalctl -xe -u croncam.service`

Comment: @gerhardd. I copied the same example 2 iterations, which ran successfully (at 02:05:21 and 02:15:22 hours), but at 02:25:13 the script stopped for some reason. https://pastebin.com/ETVmdXsN